# Backbone.js click event handler : trigger route with parameter

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-routing

I want to redirect the user to another page when they click on a button. Here's the code:

template:

```
<button type="button" id="edit-button">Edit</button>
```

router:

```
App.Router.Accounts = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'accounts/:accountID/audience/edit' : 'editAudience'
    }
});
```

view:

```
router: new App.Router.Accounts(),

events: {
    "click #edit-button": "redirectToEdit"
},

redirectToEdit: function(){
    url = "accounts/"+this.account_id+'/audience/edit';
    this.router.navigate(url, {
        trigger: true,
        replace: true
    });
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'model' in foo123
```

where foo123 is the account id.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `editAudience` look like?

Comment: it just edits the audience model and saves it ('puts' it to the server). It works fine independently (if the route is triggered directly, instead of being redirected from another view), so that's not the issue. Also, according to the error message, the error happens before the route handler gets triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the URL you can use the [`Router.navigate`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate)  method:

```
App.Router.navigate(url, {
    // trigger: true/false,
    // replace: true/false
});
```

Note that you are missing a `/` in your string concatenation.

Comment: good catch! I'm still getting the same error (I've updated the question with navigate). Did I misinterpret your solution?

Comment: actually, nvm. I deleted the cookies and history, and it worked fine. Thanks!